# Loop for items in two files

Tags: python

I have pairs of terms in this format:

```
good, bad > man, woman
```

What I need is iteration between the left and right terms in piars like the following:

```
[('good', 'man'), ('good', 'woman'), ('bad', 'man'), ('bad', 'woman')]
```

And for every new pair I have to calculate its statistics in a text file splitted by line.

Statistics:

1) Frequency of first and second items `('good','man')` when come together in a unique line in the text file;

2) Frequency of first or second items `('good' or 'man')` when one comes alone without the other in one line in the text file.

My problem here is the loop which creates false statistics.

Can someone help for good loop? Thanks

Comment: This is the fourth time you've [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199241/calculating-occurrence-of-terms-in-a-parallel-corpus) this same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200775/calculating-the-joint-and-individual-occurrence-of-pairs-of-names-in-a-text-file), on two [accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201552/error-in-loop-in-one-code).

Answer (score 2):

Your loop isn't counting properly because you're initializing the `a`, `b` and `c` variables outside of it and then using them repeatedly. Just reinitialize at the start of each `i, j` pair and you shouldn't have trouble:

```
for i in left:
        for j in right:
                a = b = c = 0                               # reinitialize!

                for line in text_file.splitlines():
                        if i in line and j in line:
                                a += 1
                        elif i in line and j not in line:
                                b+= 1
                        elif j in line and i not in line:
                                c+= 1

                bigram.append((i,j,a, b, c))
```

Comment: And bigram = [] has to be reinitialized at the start of each i, j?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know how you want the data aggregated. If you want one list of statistics for the whole dataset, leaving that outside the top loop should be fine. If you want separate stats for each line of your `pairs_file`, then you'd want to move it up to just above the `i` loop. If you want separate bigram counts for each line in `text_file`, then you'd put the `bigram` initialization right by the `a = b = c = 0` line I added, though this case doesn't make much sense since `bigram` will only ever get one value.